# Finding multiple groups in Java regex for simple option parser

Tags: java, regex

I need to modify this regex to find multiple group matches:

`(?:--)(?<key>[^\s=]+)(?:(?<assign> *[ =] *)(?! --)(?<value>"[^"]*"|\S+))?`

In Java:

`"(?:--)(?<key>[^\\s=]+)(?:(?<assign> *[ =] *)(?! --)(?<value>\"[^\"]*\"|\\S+))?"`

This matches the following correctly:

- `--key=value`
- `--key=--value`
- `--key value`
- `--flag`
- `--key="--value"`
- `--key "--value"`
- `--key=value --foo=bar`
- `--key=value --foo=bar --flag`

But it fails if `--flag` comes before any other options:

- `--key=value --flag --foo=bar`

I've been trying to modify the negative lookahead between the `assign` and `value` capture groups without success so far. The `value` captured for `flag` ends up being `--foo=bar` instead of `null`.

Any expert recommendations on how to solve this?

Comment: What about using a dedicated options parsing library?

Comment: I've considered picocli but for now it seems like overkill mainly because the regex is deployed and seems very close to working correctly. Any other library recommendations?

Comment: If you want a good answer to this, posting your unit tests for the parsing would help.

Comment: @KirkLund Have you considered [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the regex. The website https://regexr.com/ was invaluable.

The fixed regex is:

`(?<prefix>--)(?<key>[^\s=]+)(?:(?! --)(?<assign> *[ =] *)(?! --)(?<value>"[^"]*"|\S+))?`

Here's the Java class and unit test:

https://gist.github.com/kirklund/845baf340a1999a57db9e59e6ba40ce0